# powershell sharepoint if statement limited to 100 values

Tags: powershell

Currently I have this script:

```
    $User = ''
$Pass = ConvertTo-SecureString '' -AsPlainText -Force
#SharePoint online address and list name
$SPOUrl = "https://test.sharepoint.com/sites/intranet/HR"
$SPOList = "In dienst"
#Column Name mapping in SharePoint 
$SPListItemColumns = @{
        FirstName = "Title"
        LastName = "LastNamePhonetic"
        Title = "Functies"
        Managerf = "Teamleider"
        Laptop = "Laptop"
        KAgereed = "KA"
        Accountcreate="Accountcreated"
        Afdeling = "Afdelingen"
        Goedkeuring = "Goedkeuring"
}

foreach($item in $Items) {
    #Get list item for later reference
    $ListItem = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItem]$listItem = $List.GetItemById($Item.FieldValues["ID"])
        Write-Verbose "Processing list item $Firstname $LastName with ID=$($item.FieldValues["ID"])"
        #Put the fieldvalues in variables.
        Write-output $item.FieldValues[$SPListItemColumns.FirstName] $item.FieldValues[$SPListItemColumns.LastName]
        #Write-output $item.FieldValues[$SPListItemColumns.Goedkeuring]
        #Write-output $item.FieldValues[$SPListItemColumns.Accountcreate]


}
```

But it only finds the 100 first values. If I place an if statement above the write output that something that is the added at last to the list it cannot find it.

Something I can do to disable this threshold? The list is about 180 names long

Answer (score 0):

100 is default limit for SharePoint webservices. Try the code below if you just need to retreive all items from your list. This is using SP Soap, I'd think the client you are using is a wrapper of it as well, so you might find comparable methods in it too.

```bsh
$siteUrl = "https://test.sharepoint.com/sites/intranet/HR"

$list = "In dienst"

$sp = New-WebServiceProxy -Uri "$siteUrl/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx?wsdl" -UseDefaultCredential

$view = $query = $vFields = $options = $webid = $null # opt params: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/bb263567(v%3Doffice.14)

$rowLimit = 0  # include all rows

$items = $sp.GetListItems($list, $view, $query, $vFields, $rowLimit, $options, $webid)

$items.data.row | Format-Table
```